# Parallel arbitrary-precision arithmetic library

Tags: math, parallel-processing

I am trying to do modular exponentiation of integers with a very large modulus by repetitive squaring (the power is always a power of 2 in my case, so I believe this is the most efficient way).  Thanks to a nice property of my modulus, computing remainder is cheap; the hard part is multiplication.

Currently I run GMP on Intel Core 2 Quad.  I would like to make efficient use of the four cores of the processor, but GMP does not scale on SMP environments, so I am looking for a substitute arbitrary-precision arithmetic library.  I have found some libraries for parallel computation on *matrices*, but what I really need is a library for *integers*.

Does what I am looking for exist?

Comment: How big are your numbers (digits, bits)?  Even with cheap forking the context switching time to enable mulitiple CPUs to work on a single arithmetic operation might dominate any savings.  If the numbers are big enough, you ought to be do a recursive divide and conquer on add/subtract [split the number into left and right parts, recusively add the parts, propagate the carry], but I'd expect the win to be in parallelizing multiple and divide if there's a win to be had.

Comment: My moduli can be as big as 2^10000000 (!).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is yes, multi-threaded arbitrary-precision libraries ***do exist***. But I'm not aware of a single one that is actually public. (with comparable speed to GMP)

For example, the arbitrary-precision libraries that are used in the Pi-computing programs, [TachusPi](http://bellard.org/pi/pi2700e9/tpi.html) and [y-cruncher](http://www.numberworld.org/y-cruncher/) are capable of multi-threaded arithmetic on large numbers.

*However, both libraries are closed source and are not available to the public for use.*

**Affiliation Disclosure:** I'm the author of [y-cruncher](http://www.numberworld.org/y-cruncher/). So I have written one of such multi-threaded arbitrary-precision libraries myself.

Comment: Could you tell me what kind of algorithm those libraries use?  I skimmed the relevant chapters of Knuth's TAOCP, but I couldn't find bignum algorithms that are explicitly stated to be suitable for parallel computing, except so-called modular arithmetic, which turned out to be unsuitable in my case.

Comment: All the major large-number libraries use some sort of FFT to do large multiplication. FFT and it's variants are all very parallelizable. However, implementing one specialized for large-number multiplication is not an easy task. (you can't just slap a wrapper on top of FFTW and expect it to beat GMP and scale with multiple cores)

Comment: Thanks. (I rather skipped sections on FFT). I don't think, though, I can implement fast multiplication routine myself...

Comment: It's definitely a very difficult task. (which is why GMP exists in the first place) My own minimalistic implementation (that's about 50% faster than GMP - single-threaded) is more than 50,000 lines long. So it's probably easier to just wait for such a library to come into existance and become public. If you're ambitious, you could try to parallelize the GMP implementation. I haven't looked at it myself so I can't comment on how possible this is.

Comment: The GMP implementation is written in C (thank God it's not in assembly or ML) and seems to be a combination of schoolbook, Karatsuba, Toom and FFT, so you have to add four copies of parallelizing code.  Sigh.  (OT: I heard on TV that your software set the world record early in this month. Congratulations.)

Comment: You wouldn't need to bother trying to parallelize anything but the FFT. The other algorithms are only used for small sizes that are too small to gain anything from parallelism. (About the world record: Thanks! Yes it's me. You're talking to one of the two guys who did it. :D)

Answer (score 1):

Have you check out http://mpir.org?  They claim to be doing this with a variant of GMP, and using GPUs.

Comment: They list it as one of their goals. But based on their documentation, it doesn't look like any of it has been implemented. Probably because MPIR is forked off of GMP and GMP itself isn't parallelized.

Comment: That's a pity.  I could parallelize GMP myself, but how difficult is it actually?

Comment: An interesting question. If the MPIR guys are supposed to be doing this and have not, you should wonder why.    I'd expect the hard part to be getting the GMP code (written in GCC C, right) to do multithreading operations.  The goo required to do this and corresponding synchronization can be relatively messy in C.  The algorithms themselves: as I said earlier, a divide-and-conquer for add should be easy enough, and I'd expect multiply A:B by C:D to be computed primarily as computing cross products and sums should also parallelize that way.  Would it be a win?  Hard to tell without doing it.

Comment: Probably it would *not* be a win. By halving the numbers into two parts each, the time needed for each multiplication roughly halves, because multiplying n-digit long numbers takes O(n lg n) time by FFT, but you do multiplication four times, so the overall time is twice as long as the original running time.  Since there are four cores, the running time is half as long as the original one, possibly plus overhead.  But you want it to be quarter as long, if you have four cores, don't you?

Comment: If multiplication is O(n lg n), and you cut the size of n in two, (you are multiplying smaller numbers!) you get O(n/2 lg n/2) --> O(n/2 (lg n - lg 2).  The adds to reassemble the answer are O(n) dominated by the O( n ln n ) term so that's not free but uninteresting.  And you do this recursively. (The Strassen matrix multiply scheme uses something like this and is a lot faster for really  big matrices).  No, I haven't tried this.  And, getting 24-32 cores is pretty easy these days in a high end workstation.

Comment: I ignored the lg 2 term :-)  I might not want to do this recursively, because I'm planning to do this on my PC (which has only four cores), and because if you do that recursively, producing four products in each step, then you'll end up in an O(n^2) algorithm.